# Intellisense not working

Tags: intellisense

Intellisense is not working correctly for new user Controls. Any class in the same namespace as my new class is not visible in intellisense. It compiles without any problem. I'm using VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was trying to use another userControl inside my userControl and didn't register it. Since both userControls were in same namespace, it was compiling correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you restart your VS 2008 and see whether the problem goes away?

Answer (score 0):

Close visual studio, delete the ncb file, then open it again